# Redirect stdio (pipes and file descriptors) in Rust

Tags: rust, pipe, file-descriptor, stdio

My main aim is to implement a program in Rust to redirect stdio over pipes locally and is similar to this

- Program executes a command "sh" and creates pipes between the parent process and the child process
- Output from the child process goes through the pipe (in this case the prompt) to the parent process
- I type something on my terminal such as "pwd" and this goes into the pipe to the child process
- Child process executes the command and sends the output back through the pipe to the parent process and displays the current working directory on my terminal

Eventually, my aim is to have the parent process act as a proxy and forward this I/O through a TLS connection between a remote ncat instance and the child process. For now, I am trying to get the piping part right.

How should I do this? My current code snippet looks like this but I am not sure if I got the redirection part right since I don't see a prompt.

```rust
let message_string = String::from("fd_pipe\0");
let message = message_string.as_ptr() as *const c_void;

let mut command_output = std::process::Command::new("/bin/sh")
  .stdin(Stdio::piped())
  .stdout(Stdio::piped())
  .stderr(Stdio::piped())
  .spawn()
  .expect("cannot execute command");

let command_stdin = command_output.stdin.unwrap();
println!("command_stdin {}", command_stdin.as_raw_fd());

let command_stdout = command_output.stdout.unwrap();
println!("command_stdout {}", command_stdout.as_raw_fd());

let command_stderr = command_output.stderr.unwrap();
println!("command_stderr {}", command_stderr.as_raw_fd());

nix::unistd::dup2(tokio::io::stdin().as_raw_fd(), command_stdin.as_raw_fd());
nix::unistd::dup2(tokio::io::stdout().as_raw_fd(), command_stdout.as_raw_fd());
nix::unistd::dup2(tokio::io::stderr().as_raw_fd(), command_stderr.as_raw_fd());
```

EDIT 2 Nov 2020

Someone in the Rust forum has kindly provided a solution for me (https://users.rust-lang.org/t/redirect-stdio-pipes-and-file-descriptors/50751/8), I thought I will share it here as well

```
let mut command_output = std::process::Command::new("/bin/sh")
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .stderr(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .expect("cannot execute command");

let mut command_stdin = command_output.stdin.unwrap();
println!("command_stdin {}", command_stdin.as_raw_fd());

let copy_stdin_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
    io::copy(&mut io::stdin(), &mut command_stdin)
});
        
let mut command_stdout = command_output.stdout.unwrap();
println!("command_stdout {}", command_stdout.as_raw_fd());

let copy_stdout_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
   io::copy(&mut command_stdout, &mut io::stdout())
});

let command_stderr = command_output.stderr.unwrap();
println!("command_stderr {}", command_stderr.as_raw_fd());

let copy_stderr_thread = std::thread::spawn(move || {
    io::copy(&mut command_stderr, &mut io::stderr())
});

copy_stdin_thread.join().unwrap()?;
copy_stdout_thread.join().unwrap()?;
copy_stderr_thread.join().unwrap()?;
```

My next question is how do I link the redirected stdio over a TLS connection to a remote ncat listener?

Comment: You shouldn't need to dup anything, I think all you're missing is `command_output.wait()`. Can you clarify what's not working? Also `.spawn()` implies `Stdio::piped()` so those aren't needed, `Command::new("sh").spawn().unwrap().wait().unwrap()` should proxy the shell just fine.

Comment: Hi @kmdreko, thanks for the advice. I also posted a solution that someone else has kindly shared with me as well.